# How to share data between tasks correctly using mutex?

Tags: c++, arduino, freertos

I've tried to follow a several tutorials on mutexes and modified an example from Arduino IDE. Tasks work fine while running separately, but nothing happens when they are both running. I assume it's due to `ser_mode` that's shared. If it's important - I'm running it on Arduino UNO.

```
#include "MPU9250.h"
#include <Arduino_FreeRTOS.h>
#include <semphr.h>

MPU9250 IMU(Wire,0x68);
TaskHandle_t TaskBlink_Handler;
TaskHandle_t TaskSerial_Handler;
SemaphoreHandle_t mutex;
int status;
int ser_mode = 0; // 0 - Accel, 1 - Gyro, 2 - Mag

void setup() {
  status = IMU.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mutex = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();
  if (mutex != NULL) {
    Serial.println("Mutex created");
  }
  Serial.println("Serial begin!");
  while (!Serial) {
    ;
  }
  Serial.println("Serial connected!");
  xTaskCreate(TaskBlink, "Blink",  128, NULL, 1, &TaskBlink_Handler);
  xTaskCreate(TaskSerial, "Serial", 128, NULL, 1, &TaskSerial_Handler);  
  Serial.println("Tasks created successfully");
}

void loop() {
}

void TaskSerial(void *pvParameters){
  for (;;){
      while(Serial.available()>0){
        if (xSemaphoreTake(mutex, 10) == pdTRUE){
          switch(Serial.read()){
            case '0':
              Serial.println("Mode 0");
              ser_mode = 0;
              xSemaphoreGive(mutex);
              break;
            case '1':
              Serial.println("Mode 1");
              ser_mode = 1;
              xSemaphoreGive(mutex);
              break;
            case '2':
              Serial.println("Mode 2");
              ser_mode = 2;
              xSemaphoreGive(mutex);
              break;
          }
          
        }
      }
   }
}

void TaskBlink(void *pvParameters)
{
  for(;;){
    if (xSemaphoreTake(mutex, 10) == pdTRUE){
        IMU.readSensor();
        Serial.print("Current mode: ");
        Serial.println(ser_mode);
        switch(ser_mode){
          case 0:
            Serial.print(IMU.getAccelX_mss(),6);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(IMU.getAccelY_mss(),6);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(IMU.getAccelZ_mss(),6);
            Serial.print("\n");
            break;
          case 1:
            Serial.print(IMU.getGyroX_rads(),6);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(IMU.getGyroY_rads(),6);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(IMU.getGyroZ_rads(),6);
            Serial.print("\n");
            break;
          case 2:
            Serial.print(IMU.getMagX_uT(),6);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(IMU.getMagY_uT(),6);
            Serial.print("\t");
            Serial.print(IMU.getMagZ_uT(),6);
            Serial.print("\n");
            break;
          default:
            Serial.print("Please send command with a correct value (0 - Accelerometer, 1 - Gyroscope, 2 - Magnetometr)\n");
            break;
        }
    xSemaphoreGive(mutex);
    vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
  }
}
```

PS. Excuse me if your eyes hurt from seeing my code.

Comment: Always use RAII pattern for crucial resources like mutexes semaphores and so on.

Comment: Make ser_mode volatile and increase the stack size. You really should enable FreeRTOS stack overflow checking and configASSERT.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try implementing it. 
Unfortunetely making `ser_mode` volatile and increasing the stack size doesn't help. I've tried it before.

Comment: When `switch(Serial.read()){` is not `'0'` and not `'1'` and not `'2'` you do not give semaphore... just `ser_mode = Serial.read() - '0';`

Comment: Yup. I've had `xSemaphoreGive(mutex); ` after the switch, but I've changed it for the sake of changing anything so 'maybe it'll work'. But good point, I'll change it back.  
Anyways, it hasn't done much since the tasks don't even run.

Comment: OK, this was some time ago and I hope you have solved your problem already.  But just in case not....what do you mean by "the tasks don't even run"?  Have you seen, with breakpoints, stepping, etc., that the code is not running at all, even once, or do you mean that you see no output?  Also, this is not the complete code; I don't see main() and I don't see where Serial is defined -- unless in Arduino there is something standard that is done 'for you'?

Comment: So, I haven't solved it. And it is the complete code, `main` function isn't used, since there are tasks that are running using FreeRTOS.  `Serial` connection is initialized at the beggining of `setup` function, it's all that needs to be done. 
"Have you seen, with breakpoints, stepping, etc." And it's the exact problem I have. It's compiling and running, but I cannot see the runtime errors, because it's on the microcontroller. I guess there are fancy ways to debug it, but I have no knowledge about them.
Seems like I need to learn more about C/C++ and debugging it on MCU. ;p